# CSS Advanced Div Positioning. Auto Arrange to Grid

Tags: css, positioning, html

i have an dynamic image gallery to display, using PHP...

**My PROB**

[image]
the style & positioning should be that if there is not enough space for a whole div, like in the image above,  then the DIVs in the row should position them like the following

[image]centered and equi distant...

[here is JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7qBz/1) basic template set, if somebody wants to try something on jsFiddle

Comment: I don't think this is possible using CSS alone.

Comment: @casablanca you can purely do that with CSS

Comment: there will some match calculations involved in that if you are interested let me know , i can explain you in detail. Based on each row which image has more width , we have to take as maximum and same with height. We have spent enough time on this and made it configurable also, Let me know if you intested i will explain you in detail

Comment: @gov: yes calculation i can do... but i want to just get it over with using styling

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to achieve this with just CSS, the code would be as so:

```
#div {
  clear:both;
  width:500px
}
.img {
   display:block;
   width:150px;
   height: 50px;
   float:left;
}
```

As far as I remember, that's it..
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

- Never "clear" the float (at least until the end of the grid).
- Enclose each img in its own DIV with the float:left style,
- Important: Give each of those DIVs the same HEIGHT (slightly larger than the largest photo), otherwise if the images are different heights you will get some weird floating.
- Optional: If your images are different widths, and you want a nice 'grid pattern', then you can give all the DIVs a width property.
- Beware of the effects of margins on overall height/width.
- Also note that if you use the standard meta viewport tag on your pages to format them for narrow mobile screens, this will shove all your images into columns to fit that screen without shrinking them unbearably (provided something else doesn't make the page wide).

  #div {
  width: 220px;
  height: 215px;
  float: left;
  }

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve all of that simply with css width property for div

```
#div {
width:500px;
}
```

We implemented almost the same here

```
http://www.art.com/gallery/id--b1823/animals-posters.htm?ui=9E23F1D932F54F2F8F2E37851C860158
```

here also , you can switch between grid view and normal view , all we are playing around is with divs width

```
http://www.allposters.com/-st/Animal-Posters_c622_.htm
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants. Your example always has only 3 images in a row, but the OP wants the number of images to adjust based on the browser width.

Comment: using window.width or document.width we can calculate those things also

Comment: don't we have something like `float:justify` :)

Answer (score 0):

Google had the same problem with their image search... they had to overcome it with fancy scripting. Looking at the source, each row of images is a `<ul>` inside a `<span>`, and each image is in an `<li>`. Then when you resize the window, the images get moved from one `<ul>` to another. That's the best method they could come up with, apparently.

So, using jQuery:

```
blocksPerRow = Math.floor($('#container').width() / blockWidth);

$('.row ul').each(function () {
  while ($(this).children('li').size() > blocksPerRow)
    ($(this).children('li:last-child').prependTo($(this).nearest('.row').next()));
  while ($(this).children('li').size() < blocksPerRow)
    ($(this).nearest('.row').next().find('li:first-child').prependTo($(this).nearest('.row')));
});
```

I think that should do it. Add that to `$(window).resize()` as well as the `document ready` event.